# Android AIDL process not working as libary project

Tags: android, aidl

I have android project wich used the android aidl process. its working fine when i mark project as library then include that project in other project its not working.

For Example

1. 'A' Project (With AIDL Process not mark as library)
2. 'A' Project (With AIDL Process mark as library)
3. 'B' (include 'A' as library) lite version
4. 'C' (include 'A' as library) pro version
5. 'D' if I install 'A' (With AIDL Process not mark as library) project apk then 'D' is communicating with  'A' project fine with the help of AIDL process
6. 'D' if I install 'B' or 'C' project apk then 'D' is not communicating with 'b' or 'c' project.

if any one know how AIDL process can be work as library project please let me know

Thank you